# Is this written in Fath al-Bari or Shama'il Muhammadiyah?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, reference-request

The Prophet ﷺ said,

> A part of earth is present in everyone's navel with which he was created and in it he will be buried. I, Abu Bakr and Umar were created from the same earth and will be buried in it.

Someone said this is written in Fath al-Bari and Shama'il Muhammadiyah. Is it really written in these books?